# Bootstrap version 3.11 responsive footer?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like some help with my responsive bootstrap theme that I customized myself.

The problem is, there is some white part below my footer after the light-blue jumbotron.

I'd like my footer to be so that it goes on top of the jumbotron and not after the white part.

You can view here: enfriend.tk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your page...

```
<style type="text/css">
.jumbotron
{
  margin-bottom:0;
}
</style>
```

Looks like the .jumbotron class has a 30px margin on the bottom.  If you override the class, it should fix.

Also, you have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css.  You only need one or the other.  Use the "min" version for production...the other can be used while debugging.

Comment: The style tag should be added after you load bootstrap to override the style.